# Неправильная работа кода

Tags: python

Пишу бота для ВК Сообщества на Python.

Написал:

```
if 'хорошо' in msg_casefold or 'отлично' in msg_casefold or 'супер' in msg_casefold or 'офигено' in msg_casefold or 'офигенно' in msg_casefold or 'афигено' in msg_casefold or 'ах#ено' in msg_casefold or 'ах#енно' in msg_casefold or 'за#бись' in msg_casefold or 'за#бок' in msg_casefold or 'класс' in msg_casefold or 'клас' or 'топ' in msg_casefold:
    answered = True
    maybe_answer = ['Отлично, когда всё супер!', 'Вот и классненько', 'Супер!', 'Вот и хорошо!']
    answer = random.choice(maybe_answer)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    sender(id, answer)
```

Поясню:

`answered = True` нужно для того, чтобы Бот мог определить:  будет ли получен ответ на сообщение или нет. Для этого, в тот момент, как сообщество получит новое сообщение переменная `answered = False`.
В конце, если сообщение не было равно чему-то из доступного (т.е. `answered = False`), то он выводит реакцию на неизвестную команду.

`sender(id, text)` - функция, которую я уже прописал в самом начале кода, чтобы тратить меньше времени на код для вывода текста.

Теперь же, после написания *виновной части кода*, то теперь всегда выводится текст этого параметра, не смотря на сообщение, даже если в сообщении **не было нужного текста**.

Что делать?

Больше кода:

```
    try:
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                answered = False
                
                if event.to_me:
                    
                    if event.from_user and not event.from_chat:
                        
                        v=0

                        if re.search(r'\bку\b', msg_lower):
                            v=1
                        if 'прив' in msg_lower or 'здравст' in msg_lower or 'здраст' in msg_lower or 'здаров' in msg_lower or 'здоров' in msg_lower or v==1:
                            v=0
                            answered = True
                            maybe_answer = ['Привет, '+nickname+'!', 'Здравствуйте, '+nickname+'!', 'Привет! Как дела, '+nickname+'?']
                            answer = random.choice(maybe_answer)
                            time.sleep(0.5)
                            sender(id, answer)

                        if 'как' in msg_lower and 'дела' in msg_lower:
                            answered = True
                            maybe_answer = ['У нас всё путём, по-летнему :D', 'У нас всё отлично! А у Вас?', 'У нас отлично, а у Вас, '+nickname+'?']
                            answer = random.choice(maybe_answer)
                            time.sleep(0.5)
                            sender(id, answer) 

                        answered = False
                        if 'хорошо' in msg_lower or 'отлично' in msg_lower or 'супер' in msg_lower or 'офигено' in msg_lower or 'офигенно' in msg_lower or 'афигено' in msg_lower or 'ах#ено' in msg_lower or 'ах#енно' in msg_lower or 'за#бись' in msg_lower or 'за#бок' in msg_lower or 'класс' in msg_lower or 'клас' or 'топ' in msg_lower:
                            answered = True
                            maybe_answer = ['Отлично, когда всё супер!', 'Вот и классненько', 'Супер!', 'Вот и хорошо!']
                            answer = random.choice(maybe_answer)
                            time.sleep(0.5)
                            sender(id, answer)

                        if 'спасибо' in msg_lower or 'спс' in msg_lower or 'посиб' in msg_lower or 'пасиб' in msg_lower:
                            answered = True
                            maybe_answer = ['Рады Вам помочь!', 'Пожалуйста =)']
                            answer = random.choice(maybe_answer)
                            time.sleep(0.5)
                            sender(id, answer)

                        if re.search(r'\bпока\b', msg_lower):
                            v=1
                        if v==1:
                            v=0
                            answered = True
                            maybe_answer = ['Пока, удачи!', 'Удачи, '+nickname+'!', 'Пока!', 'До встречи!', 'Пока, '+nickname+'!', 'До встречи, '+nickname+'!']
                            answer = random.choice(maybe_answer)
                            time.sleep(0.5)
                            sender(id, answer)


                    if event.from_user:           
                        if answered == True:
                            pass
                        if answered == False:
                            time.sleep(0.5)
                            sender(id, idu)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробую поиграть в угадайку:

```
WORDS_LIST = ['хорошо', 'отлично', 'супер', 'офигено', 'офигенно', 'афигено', 'ах#ено', 'ах#енно', 'за#бись', 'за#бок', 'класс', 'клас', 'топ']

answered = True if any([w in msg_casefold for w in WORDS_LIST]) else False
if answered:
    maybe_answer = ['Отлично, когда всё супер!', 'Вот и классненько', 'Супер!', 'Вот и хорошо!']
    answer = random.choice(maybe_answer)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    sender(id, answer)
```

Comment: Я немного подкорректировал Ваш код под нужные данные и всё заработало, как надо!
Спасибо большое!

Comment: Рад, что подошло)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно `answered` опять присвоить `False`.

Comment: Нет, не помогло. Сейчас попробую переписать эту часть

Comment: Так надо в нужном месте. Например, непосредственно перед if.

Comment: Гм... Не-а. Ничего не помогает.
Она просто забирает себе действие другой части кода каким-то образом...

Comment: Тогда надо в вопрос добавить больше кода, а то сейчас непонятно, что там вокруг происходит.

Comment: Окей, сейчас добавлю